# use of reinterpret_cast while reading value from binary file

Tags: c++, reinterpret-cast

Let's suppose `head1` is an 2D array of float and I want to fill it with values read from the binary file `file`.
After opening the file with

`ifstream file ("myfile.bin", ios::in|ios::binary);`

I tried two different ways:

1. `file.read( reinterpret_cast<char*>(&head1), sizeof(head1) );`
2. `file.read( (char*) &head1, sizeof(head1) );`

Both solutions work, but what's exactly the difference between them? which is "safer"?
After reading some documentation, for me the role of `reinterpret_cast` is still a bit obscure and from "Programming: Principles and Practice Using C++" I also read that is better to use this function only if necessary especially for portability problem.
Thanks

Comment: check my question about binary files https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70405642/how-to-store-class-object-having-string-in-binary-file

Comment: This is an occasion when using `reinterpret_cast` is acceptable, IMHO. And that is *always* better than using a "c-style" cast. Note also, that if `head1` is a plain array, you don't need the `&` before it, as it will "decay" to a pointer to its first element in most expressions.

Comment: attention: sizeof() only works for static arrays, not for ```float* head1 = new float[1024];```. Here, sizeof() returns the size of a pointer variable (4 or 8 bytes e.g.).